# Revit API: Get generating profiles of a solid form

Tags: revit-api

I selected some FamilyInstances and clicked "Create Form -> Solid Form".
How can I get the generating FamilyInstance(s), if I only have the Form?

```
        var form = ele as Autodesk.Revit.DB.Form;
        int nSub = form.ProfileCount; // <<<< 28 - I want a reference to each ElementId!

        // form.GetGeneratingElementIds();             // only one
        // form.GetMonitoredLinkElementIds();          // zero
        // form.get_CurveLoopReferencesOnProfile(0,0); // ReferenceArray of 9 items
```

If it's impossible - can it be done the other way round? Like: I have a family_instance and try to find the "parent" Form.

Comment: are you in a family definition? i don't understand. you would have either a nested family instance within the family definition, or a form. i would have thought they would be two independent sources of geometry?

Comment: I am in a family. My nesting is like this:  

**[A]** Mass-based family = cross-section definition (parameters: widthA1, widthA2)  

**[B]** Adaptive family = cross section family (parameter: Bwidth sets e.g. mass.widthA1=formula(widthB); mass.widthA2=formula(widthB+1.0), ... )  

**[C]** Generic model based family. Here I have 2 instances of the [B] cross section and a Form **[D]** that envelopes them.  

 
So, given the Form [D], how can I get the real values of the family [A] parameters width1 and width2?

Comment: it may help to open the nested documents using `EditFamily` and snoop through everything in detail.

Comment: Sorry - I had two problems in mind and my last comment was (partially) incorrect. My real problem is: I have a Form **A**, and I have a list of FamilyInstances **B**, that are used to generate the form. Also I have familyinstances **C**, that are NOT part of the form A. So, how can I determine **which** familyinstances are part of the form?